# Does Spring Boot with its Blocking IO really fit well with Microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, blocking

There are a lot of tutorials and articles (including official site) promoting spring boot as a good tool for building microservices.

Let's say we have some rest api endpoint (User profile) which aggregates data from multiple services (User service, Stat service, Friends service).

To achieve this, user profile endpoint makes 3 http calls to those services.

But in Spring, requests are blocking and as I see, the server will quickly run out of available resources (threads) to serve request in such system.

So to me, it as quite inefficient way to build such systems (compared to non-blocking frameworks, like play! framework or node.js)

Do I miss something?

P.S.: I do not mean here spring 5 with its new webflux framework.

Comment: Microservices is not about building non-blocking systems or services. It's about building small, self-contained services that can scale, and can be deployed in isolation. To address blocking IO problem is outside of scope of microservice architecture.

Comment: Yes, but often microservices communicate over http with each other (at least I see many tutorials, including spring boot tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

No one prevents you from building an asynchronous microservice architecture with Spring Boot :).

Something along these lines:

[image]

Instead of one service calling another synchronously, a service can put events to a queue (e.g. RabbitMQ). The events are delivered to services that subscribe to those events.

Using RabbitMQ and its "exchange" concept, the event producing service doesn't even need to the consumers of its events.

A blog post detailing this with Spring Boot code can be found here: https://reflectoring.io/event-messaging-with-spring-boot-and-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a limitation of Spring rather it is more to do with the Application Architecture.

For instance, the scenario that you have is commonly solved using Aggregate Design Pattern
[image]

While this solution is quite prevalent,it has the limitation of being synchronous, and thus blocking. Asynchronous behaviour in such scenarios should be implemented in an application specific way.

Having said that if you have to call other services in order to be able to serve a response to a request from a client(outside), this is typically an architectural problem. It really doesn’t matter if you are using HTTP or asynchronous message passing (with a request-reply pattern), the overall response time for the outside client will be bad

Also, I have seen quite a few applications which uses synchronous REST calls for external clients, but when communication is needed between internal MicroServices, it should always be asynchronous. You can read an interesting paper on this topic here [MicroServices Messaging Patterns](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf)